# Calculating errors based on other variables

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, units, error-analysis, statistics

I am trying to calculate the mass and respective error of a star in kg. I have the numbers in units of $M_{Sun}$,in the form $M_{star}=(a\pm b)$ $M_{Sun}$.
Given that I have the mass (with error) of the Sun in kg, in the form $M_{Sun}=(c\pm d)kg$, how can I use this to convert the mass and error of the star to kg?

Comment: do you mean Mstar=MSun*(b+-a)? otherwise your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: You are just multiplying together two numbers, each of which has an uncertainty, but one of which is surely negligible. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Are a and b known precisely or do they also have errors?

Comment: $M_{star}=(a\pm b) M_{Sun}=(aM_{Sun}) \pm (b M_{Sun})$.

Comment: yes sorry, @sammygerbil is correct, that's what I meant. a and b don't have uncertainties, but the mass of the Sun does. My problem is how to use (if I should) the uncertainty in the mass of the Sun when converting units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass of the star is the product of two numbers. The two numbers have uncertainties and so does the product : $$p\pm q=(a\pm b)(c\pm d)$$ The uncertainty in the product is given by $$(\frac{q}{p})^2=(\frac{b}{a})^2+(\frac{d}{c})^2$$ where $p=ac$.

If $\frac{b}{a} \gt 3\frac{d}{c}$ then it makes little difference if you ignore $d$ and simply use $$p\pm q \approx (a\pm b)c=(ac)\pm (bc)$$

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the **scale**. Thus, you don't have to worry about the uncertainties. As long as the scaling is linear, you can translate the values similar to changing money to a foreign language. And since I want you to understand this, I'm explaining it by using the money example:

Currently, 1USD corresponds to 0.9Euro. We are going to a trip to Europe and we like to change our money. However,  since we are lazy, we do not count the    money in our wallets but only estimate it. Let's say our estimate yields that we have $(300 \pm 45)$USD. How much Euros do we get?

The answer is given by replacing $1\cdot$USD by $0.9\cdot$Euro. Hence, we write 
$$
(300 \pm 45)\textrm{USD} 
= (300 \pm 45)\cdot 0.9\cdot \textrm{Euro}
= (270 \pm 40.5)\textrm{Euro}
$$

Comment: So should I just ignore the error in the mass of the Sun? In your example you have that 1USD corresponds to 0.9Euro, but what if you had that 1USD corresponded to like (0.9$\pm$0.1) Euro?

Comment: If this is what is you're interested in, then it's mathematically straight forward: Assuming independence of the variables, you are allowed to multiple the terms one by one. However, make sure that this was intend when $M_{star}$ was measured. So you need to take a close look on how the measurement was done, from which you obtained $M_{star}$. Probably, they did not account for the inaccuracy of $M_{sun}$, but only took the expected value.